# Fill area below two curves in limited area

Tags: plotting, filling

I need to fill a region in my plot (The white area in the bottom between the two graphs going to the x axis. I cannot figure out a way to do this, please help.

```
mbbNH[s12sq_, s13sq_, m1_, dmatm_, dmsol_, α_, β_] := Abs[(1 - s12sq) (1 - s13sq) m1 + Exp[I α] s12sq (1 - s13sq) Sqrt[m1^2 + dmsol] + Exp[I β] s13sq Sqrt[m1^2 + dmatm]];
NO = LogLogPlot[
  {
   mbbNH[0.272, 0.02436, m1, 2.593 10^-3, 6.80 10^-5, π, 0],
   mbbNH[0.346, 0.02436, m1, 2.593 10^-3, 8.02 10^-5, π, π],
   mbbNH[0.346, 0.02436, m1, 2.593 10^-3, 6.80 10^-5, 0, 0]
   },
  {m1, 10^(-4), 1},
  PlotRange -> {{10^(-4), 1}, {10^(-4), 1}},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Red],
  Filling -> {1 -> {3}, 1 -> {2}, 2 -> {3}},
  AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[Subscript[m, light] "(eV)"], HoldForm[Subscript[m, ββ] "(eV)"]},
  PlotLabel -> None, LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]},
  GridLines -> {
    {0.23},
    {{0.061, Red}, {0.165, Red}, {0.11, Blue}, {0.52, Blue}, {0.19, Green}, {0.45, Green}, {0.2, Purple}, {0.4, Purple}, {0.3, Gray}, {0.9, Gray}}
    },
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed]
  ]
```

[image]

I am trying to get it like the this, but uniformly colored red:

[image]

Comment: Related: [(40146)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40146/), [(14696)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14696/), [(130050)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130050/), [(109442)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109442/), [(20721)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20721/), [(59076)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59076/), [(96521)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96521/). Also, you might want to read the documentation of [`Filling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html).

Comment: Did you even look at the linked questions? The first one covers exactly that...

Comment: Of course I looked at them. I had already looked through the forum before I posted. They do not work with what I have.

Comment: In that case it might be a good idea to show that you've done so (i.e. show a few attempts and how they differ from what you want ) - this makes it easier to help you efficiently

Comment: I got it to work when I use piecewise method. However, some of the shaded areas overlap, so they are not all the same color, some stronger colored than others.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution:

```
mbbNH[s12sq_, s13sq_, m1_, dmatm_, dmsol_, α_, β_] := Abs[(1 - s12sq) (1 - s13sq) m1 + Exp[I α] s12sq (1 - s13sq) Sqrt[m1^2 + dmsol] + Exp[I β] s13sq Sqrt[m1^2 + dmatm]];
NO = LogLogPlot[
  Evaluate[{Min@Append[#, Piecewise[{{10^(-5), 0.0015 <= m1 <= 0.0085}}, Infinity]], Max@#} &@{
     mbbNH[0.272, 0.02436, m1, 2.593 10^-3, 6.80 10^-5, π, 0],
     mbbNH[0.346, 0.02436, m1, 2.593 10^-3, 8.02 10^-5, π, π],
     mbbNH[0.346, 0.02436, m1, 2.593 10^-3, 6.80 10^-5, 0, 0]
     }],
  {m1, 10^(-4), 1},
  PlotRange -> {{10^(-4), 1}, {10^(-4), 1}},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Red],
  Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
  AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[Subscript[m, light] "(eV)"], HoldForm[Subscript[m, ββ] "(eV)"]},
  PlotLabel -> None, LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]},
  GridLines -> {
    {0.23},
    {{0.061, Red}, {0.165, Red}, {0.11, Blue}, {0.52, Blue}, {0.19, Green}, {0.45, Green}, {0.2, Purple}, {0.4, Purple}, {0.3, Gray}, {0.9, Gray}}
    },
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The idea is to take the `Min`/`Max` of all the curves, where we add a `Piecewise` function with a constant value of $10^{-5}$ between $0.0015$ and $0.0085$ to the functions where `Min` is applied.

Comment: Thanks @Mathe172, but what I am trying to achieve is just getting the blank bit incorporated into the plot, so it will all be the same color, and then change Opacity to [0]. The lines are just there atm so I can see what I'm doing. I am trying to get it like the [this](https://imgur.com/a/fKcPukg), but uniformly colored red.

Comment: Third function is replaced with {mbbNH[0.346, 0.02436, m1, 2.593 10^-3, 6.80 10^-5, 0, 0], 
  Piecewise[{{mbbNH[0.346, 0.02436, m1, 2.593 10^-3, 6.80 10^-5, 0, 
      0], 0.0015 <= m1 <= 0.0085}}]}},

Comment: @Macempty like this?

Comment: Fantastico! Thanks a lot for your help with this! :-)